# Software which integrates project management, routines and daily todolist

Tags: project-management, time-management, todo

Lately I have been looking for a software to better organize  my life.
I found a plethora of project management software, todolist software and other stuff.
What I really need is a software which deals with  three kind of things I need to do every day:

- tasks from one of my projects
- tasks from one of my routines
- unforeseen  isolated (unrelated to any project or routine) tasks

So I would need a software which allows me to define multiple projects (each with wbs, gantt chart and mile stones), multiple routines each one broken down with many tasks and date/time, and finally a today todolist/ calendar todolist which tells me when I should perform each task and allows me to add additional task unrelated to any project and routine.
And also if one day I miss a scheduled  task  or I need to add too many extra tasks, it reschedules automatically which day I should perform the  tasks with lower priority (which is impossible to perform the same day for lack of time resources)  according to some preset constraints.
It would  also be helpful if it could make visual maps of all projects and routines, as well of all tasks along weeks and months.

Does anybody know anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Asana](http://asana.com) -  it has excellent integration of both professional and personal tasks with the ability to set repeat tasks for routines (e.g. clear your inbox every two days, have a haircut every two weeks etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://weekplan.net

> tasks from one of my projects

There is a place where you can store lists of tasks. A list can represents your projects.

> tasks from one of my routines

You can create repeating tasks

> unforeseen isolated (unrelated to any project or routine) tasks

Just add the task to your schedule.